# C# sorting files by date and time

Tags: c#, sorting, date

I've problem with sorting files by date; this's my sample code :

```
    string[] files = new string {"file1.txt", "file3.txt", "file4.txt"}
    var list = new List<string> {"10/03/2015", "01/01/2015", "20/08/2015"};
    list.Sort((a, b) => a.CompareTo(b));
```

I wanna get in the output all files sorting by date without losing the order between each file and its time:

```
// file3.txt  01/01/2015
// file1.txt  10/03/2015
// file4.txt  20/08/2015
```

So my question is how can I according **files** to sort of date, Thanks :)

Comment: How are the list and the files array related? `file2.txt` is ignored in the output but I can't see why. Alternatively, you can get the created/last read/last write times from the file itself and sort with that.

Comment: sorry I made mistake, try to forgot the : file2.txt

Comment: Ah okay. Is the list getting the date from a separate file or are you happy to get the date using the .NET framework methods such as [File.GetCreationTime](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.getcreationtime%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Easily done with Linq. First, [Zip](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/dd267698%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) together your two collections and parse the dates:

```
var filesAndDates = files
     .Zip(list,
          (filename,dateString) => new{filename, 
                                       date = DateTime.ParseExact(
                                                dateString,
                                                "dd/MM/yyyy",
                                                CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)});
```

then order them:

```
var orderedFilesAndDates = filesAndDates.OrderBy(x => x.date);
```

I find myself wondering how you ended with 2 "synchronized" lists of stuff. You could make a composite type and keep them in a single list. It's far easier to manage that way...

Comment: is there something without Linq, I want stay on .net 2.0

Answer (score 0):

first you need to parse the values to DateTime type and then do sort.

Comment: okay I did that, but than, how can I make a relation between files and Date after sorting?

Comment: build a class that defined the file name and the datetime